# if App locale is different from System locale how to fetch system locale?

Tags: android, locale

I'm setting my App locale different from system(device) locale.
example : 
App locale set is Chinese.
System locale set is English.

Now within my app if i try to fetch system locale it returns Chinese language only. Reason i noticed is app context was used to fetch system locale.

Below API's i tried but didnt work :

- mcontext.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
- Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you change the locale on your app programmatically? if this is the case, may be you can try the the System's resources object:

```
Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale;
```

and On devices with Android N and later:

```
Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have put get current Locale code.

```
Locale getCurrentLocale(Context context){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
        return context.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
    } else{
        //noinspection deprecation
        return context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
    }
}
```